# MongoDB .find() equivalent for SELECT row WHERE field = value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

New to using MongoDB and node, thanks for the help. I'd like to return two fields from a document if the email in the request body matches the email in the database. Here's what I have right now:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body);
    const user = User.collection.find({username: req.body.username}, {username: 1, password: 1});
    console.log(user);
    if(user == null) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Cannot find user with that username' });
    }
    try {
        if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
            res.status(201).json(user)
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ authenticated: false })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err })
    }
});
```

I think the user.password is undefined so it's triggering the catch call and returning a status of 500.

The output from my `console.log(user)` returns a cursor object with a whole bunch of data. In the cursor object there is an options object which shows the options I passed {username: 1, password: 1}. There is also a cmd object which has a query field with the value {username: 'GivenUsername'}

Nowhere in any of the output do I see the data I'm trying to query. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you take out the `async` and `await`?

Comment: @and1 app responds with "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection.find()` returns a *[cursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/cursors/#cursors)*. You can use its [`next()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/cursors/#get-a-single-document) method to get a single document (don't forget to check for `hasNext()` if needed) or [`toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/cursors/#get-all-documents-at-once) method to get all documents at once.

P.S. don't forget that you need to `return` your response in your `if/else/catch` blocks.

**Update**: you should use it like this:

```js
const cursor = User.collection.find({username: req.body.username}, {username: 1, password: 1});
if(!(await cursor.hasNext())) {
  return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Cannot find user with that username' });
}
const user = await cursor.next();
try {
  if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
    return res.status(201).json(user)
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ authenticated: false })
  }
} catch (err) {
  return res.status(500).json({ message: err })
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example of how to use next() with my code? I tried to console.log(user.next()) and it does indeed return the data I'm looking for, however, when I use that to check the password it doesn't seem to work and I'm still getting the 500 status.

`if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.next().password))`

Comment: @Isaac Updated my answer.

Comment: Aaaaah. Thank you so much. So looks like my if condition for user == null needed to check hasNext then to see if they exist. Sorry for making you hold my hand on this one but thanks for the concise answer. Really clears this up for me.